# SVN errorcode=2 Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: svn, mac-osx, mamp

I've got MAMP running (XAMP for OSX), and I'm trying to setup subversion.

When I go to the freshly created repository in my browser, I get:

```
<D:error>
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="2">
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

The repository is setup in my server directory. My php files are also there, and it works fine. My basic httpd.conf setup:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNPath ~/server/svntest
(Authenticaton will be added later)
</Location>
```

I've allready chmod'ed everything to 777

```
drwxrwxrwx   9 gerrit  staff       306 27 okt  2008 svn
```

Apache's errorlog does not show any errors.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991243/svn-errorcode2-could-not-open-the-requested-svn-filesystem

Comment: Yeah, I kind of cheated by crossposting it both to StackOVerflow and ServerFault. It's both programming and server maintenance related, in a way. On both sites, there is a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a repository or a working copy at ~/server/svntest?  It has to be a repository and looking at your ls -l, it looks like a working copy.

It's also best to use an absolute path for SVNPath, not ~

Comment: Changed ~ to the absolute path, and it fixed the problem